# Issue in converting little Endian hexdump output to Big Endian (C-programming)

Tags: c, endianness

I'm struggling with a problem that requires I perform a hex dump to an object file I've created with the function fopen().

I've declared the necessary integer variable (in HEX) as follows:

```
//Declare variables
    int code = 0xCADE;
```

The output must be big Endian so I've swapped the bytes in this manner:

```
//Swap bytes
    int swapped = (code>>8) | (code<<8);
```

I then opened the file for binary output in this manner:

```
//Open file for binary writing
    FILE *dest_file = fopen(filename, "wb");
```

Afterwards, I write the variable code (which corresponds to a 16 bit word) to the file in the following manner using fwrite():

```
//Write out first word of header (0xCADE) to file
    fwrite(&swapped, sizeof(int), 1, dest_file);
```

After compiling, running, and performing a hexdump on the file in which the contents have been written to, I observe the following output:

```
0000000 ca de ca 00                                    
0000004
```

Basically everything is correct up until the extra "ca 00". I am unsure why that is there and need it removed so that my output is just:

```
0000000 ca de                                    
0000004
```

I know the Endianness problem has been addressed extensively on the stack, but after performing a serach, I am unclear as to how to classify this problem. How can I approach this problem so that "ca 00" is removed?

Thanks very much.

EDIT:

I've changed both:

```
 //Declare variables
        int code = 0xCADE;

//Swap bytes
        int swapped = (code>>8) | (code<<8);
```

to:

```
//Declare variables
    unsigned short int code = 0xCADE;

//Swap bytes
    unsigned short int swapped = (code>>8) | (code<<8);
```

And I observe:

```
0000000 ca de 00 00                                    
0000004
```

Which gets me closer to what I need but there's still that extra "00 00". Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Please make a [mcve], this is more of a code puzzle.

Comment: If you only want 2 bytes stored in the file then write 2 bytes, not 4.

Comment: Use `htons()`/`ntohs()` if you're on a little-endian machine.  See https://linux.die.net/man/3/ntohs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are telling `fwrite` to write `sizeof(int)` bytes, which on your system evaluates to 4 bytes (the size of `int` is 4). If you want to write two bytes, just do:

```
fwrite(&swapped, 2, 1, dest_file);
```

Answer (score 0):

To reduce confusion, code that reorders bytes should use bytes (`uint8` or `char`) and not multi-byte types like `int`.

To swap two bytes:

```
char bytes[2];
char temp;

fread(bytes, 2, 1, file1);

temp = bytes[0];
bytes[0] = bytes[1];
bytes[1] = temp;

fwrite(bytes, 2, 1, file2);
```

If you use `int`, you probably deceive yourself assuming that its size is 2 (while it's most likely 4), and assuming anything about how your system writes `int` to files, which may be incorrect. While if you work with bytes, there cannot be any surprises - your code does exactly what it looks like it does.